# Cannot Write in Named Pipe

Tags: c, pipe, mkfifo

In this code my program crashes in when I am opening the pipe for writing.

```
char pipe[30];
int fd, tmp = 2;
sprintf(pipe, "root_%d", getpid());
ret_val = mkfifo(pipe, 0666);
fd = open(pipe, O_WRONLY); //HERE IS CRASHING - SUDDENLY FREEZES
write(fd, &tmp, sizeof(int));
close(fd)
```

All seems good, but where is my mistake;

Comment: Please post a proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please include that stack trace (e.g. from gdb).

Comment: Add error checking and handling for starters. And what is `temp`? And what line is your debugger showing the crash on? For that matter, what do you mean by crash?

Comment: Okay I edited it guys

Comment: It's still far from an [mcve]. Did you read the link?

Comment: @Broman i am sorry for you

Answer (score 1):

It is an expected behavior. From `man 7 fifo`:

> Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also.

So your `open` does not return until somebody opens the same pipe for reading. You may want to add `O_NONBLOCK` flag (and likely get `SIGPIPE` on writing), or revisit the design.